# Can you get "stereo" audio on a videocamera with a wireless microphone using a 3.5mm plug?

Tags: stereo

I have a Canon Vixia HD Camcorder which has a 3.5mm stereo input and yet cannot get stereo sound input from a wireless microphone system when using the 1/4" outlet plug and using an adapter down to 3.5mm plug into the camcorder.

I want to record in stereo,but it appears the only way to do it is with a balanced output and an adapter from a balanced 3 prong plug and then use a 3.5mm adapter plug to plug into the input on the camcorder.  Or I seem to have to run the 3 prong through a mixer and then use an output to the camcorder.  All of that sounds too complex and unnecessary to me.  I'd like to know if there's a simpler and more elegant way to accomplish it.

Comment: I’m not sure what you are trying to achieve. Do you want a stereo image from a stereo wireless microphone, or the same signal from one mono mic on both the left and right channel?

Answer (score 2):

Almost all wireless microphones only have a single Channel.  Even you are using Stereo microphone, only one channel is transmitted to the receiver.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like your 1/4" adapter is either faulty or the wrong connectivity. You have stereo inputs, you just need to ensure they are connected correctly.

Check to see whether a signal path is short circuited for one of the channels when you use the adapter, and get a different one if necessary.